# finding the minimum number of lines to cover all zeros in an assignment problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have been trying to follow the following steps to find the minimum number of horizontal and vertical lines that cover all the zeros in an assignment problem using Hungarian method:

Tick all unassigned rows.

If the ticked row has zeros, then tick the corresponding column.

Within the ticked column, if there is an assignment, then tick the corresponding row.

Draw a line through each un-ticked row and ticked column.

Repeat for each unassigned row.

Then find Theta (which is the smallest uncovered value)

The problem is when I do that, I still have zeros uncovered! causing Theta to be zero and go to an infinite loop!

The question is :

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        2 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 1 \\
        6 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 1 \\
        4 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 1 \\
        5 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

After subtracting the row minimum from the corresponding row and column minimum from the corresponding column i got :

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 7 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
        4 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 0 \\
        2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Now when i used the algorithm given above for covering all the zeros i got:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{7} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{4} & \color{red}{0} \\
        4 & 6 & 5 & 3 & \color{red}{0} \\
        \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{4} & \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} \\
        \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{5} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} \\
        3 & 1 & 7 & 2 & \color{red}{0} \\ 
        \end{matrix}
$$

Red rows and columns represent the ones covered (found according to the above steps).

After this i added and subtracted $1$ from the relevant positions to get the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 7 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\
        3 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
        2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Using the same method given above for covering all zeros i got the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{7} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{4} & \color{red}{1} \\
        3 & \color{red}{5} & 4 & 2 & \color{red}{0} \\
        \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{4} & \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
        2 & \color{red}{0} & 5 & \color{blue}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
        2 & \color{red}{0} & 6 & 1 & \color{red}{0} \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I don't understand why one zero is being left out (colored blue) ?

I figured that instead of striking out the third column if i striked out the fourth column then i would get an optimal solution.

But i don't understand why this doesn't happen, using the steps given above?

Where have i gone wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your expression "row and column minimum".

Comment: @Doc I simply meant  subtracting the row minimum from the corresponding row and column minimum from the corresponding column, i have rectified that in my post

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm. What is an assignment? An unassigned row? What does it mean to tick something? Your initial matrix has no zeros, why are you doing any steps to it?

Comment: @user7530 i forgot to mention i am trying to use the Hungarian method to solve the assignment problem

Comment: @johny, do you have a reference or text that gives these steps?  I wouldn't mind taking a look.  And also find out why it's called an "assignment problem."

Comment: Wow, really ... I normally use the Kuhn-Minkres Al;gorithm to solve the assignment problem.  I'm definitely interested in a reference.  What you're providing here has too many undefined terms.

Comment: @Doc I got this algorithm from a video lecture on youtube, the link is,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUGIhEecipE. Hope that you can help me out with this i am really stuck !

Comment: I'll do my best.  Btw, generally speaking, beware youtube.  They often show nice little "tricks" that only work part of the time.

Comment: just sayin, this is IIT Madras .. This is a legit video.

Comment: Look at the first matrix after the one with red lines in it.  The entry in row 2 and column 4 is wrong.  It should be $2$.  Fix it, and get back to me.

Comment: @Doc i fixed it, it should have been a $2$ instead of a $3$

Comment: I got to the part where you got "stuck" and I see NO ERROR in your work.  It would seem there's no way out of this.  Did the prof mention anything toward the end of the video about infinite loop/backtracking?

Comment: Here's what I'm not 100% sure of.  Ordinarily I would not tick line 4 because it has two zeros.  But the assignment in line 3 eliminated one of those two zeros.  At least the way I interpret the algorithm, this elimination meant that the sole remaining zero in line 4 could be assigned.  It thus got ticked because it is in a row that has an assigned zero in a column that got ticked.  Do you agree?  Can't see where we are going wrong.

Comment: @Doc Well i believe one could think of it that way,but there is an optimal solution to this problem,$13$, and proceeding this way is definitely not going to lead us there.It has worked for every other problem i have tried this far, but this particular one has made me doubt its ability.

Comment: @Doc Thanks for your effort though, i really appreciate it !

Comment: @johny Forget the video.  Do it this way: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/20_spring_05/handouts/assignment_overheads.pdf  Good luck.

Comment: @Doc I really liked it, easy to understand,thanks a ton ! I have an exam soon, this will definitely be very helpful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kinda late ;-) and I'm sure you've moved on, but here it is - the steps to draw a minimum number of lines should be a little different:

1. Tick all unassigned rows
2. Tick all (unticked) columns that have zeros in ticked rows
3. Tick all (unticked) rows that have assigned zeros in ticked columns
4. **Go back to point 2 unless there are no more columns that need ticking**
5. Draw a line through every ticked column and every unticked row.

If we stop ticking prematurely, we may miss some zeros. It works on the matrix you provided. This is a part of the solution of the *assignment problem* with the *Hungarian Method* (or the *Hungarian algorithm*), see Wikipedia for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation

Comment: @ooo Well, thanks! This is certainly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The method given by you for covering all the zeros with minimum lines works in the later matrix as well.

If after assigning, we start with unassigned rows then the process goes as follows.

The 5th row is ticked.

Then 2nd and 5th column are ticked.

Then 2nd and 4th row are ticked as they have assignments.

Then 4th column is ticked as it has a 0 in the 4th row.

Then 3rd row are ticked as it has assignment.

This gives 1st row un-ticked and 2nd, 4th and 5th row ticked through which minimum lines can be drawn to cover all the zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the Wikipedia article and I made an implementation that seems to work all the time. @000 answer helped me a lot with this but I figured I would post my code if anybody finds it useful to see how I did it. (note this is just for step which is what the OP was having trouble with.

Basically as long as there is still a zero which isn't covered the code repeats 2,3 and 4.

Ruby Code:

```
 
def draw_lines grid
    #copies the array   
    marking_grid = grid.map { |a| a.dup }

    marked_rows = Array.new
    marked_cols = Array.new

    while there_is_zero(marking_grid) do 
        marking_grid = grid.map { |a| a.dup }

        marked_cols.each do |col|
            cross_out(marking_grid,nil, col)
        end

        marked = assignment(grid, marking_grid) 
        marked_rows = marked[0]
        marked_cols.concat(marked[1]).uniq!

        marking_grid = grid.map { |a| a.dup }

        marking_grid.length.times do |row|
            if !(marked_rows.include? row) then
                cross_out(marking_grid,row, nil)
            end
        end

        marked_cols.each do |col|
            cross_out(marking_grid,nil, col)
        end
    end


    lines = Array.new

    marked_cols.each do |index|
        lines.push(["column", index])
    end
    grid.each_index do |index|
        if !(marked_rows.include? index) then
            lines.push(["row", index])
        end
    end
    return lines
end


def there_is_zero grid
    grid.each_with_index do |row|
        row.each_with_index do |value|
            if value == 0 then
                return true
            end
        end
    end
    return false
end

def assignment grid, marking_grid 
    marking_grid.each_index do |row_index|
        first_zero = marking_grid[row_index].index(0)
        #if there is no zero go to next row
        if first_zero.nil? then
            next        
        else
            cross_out(marking_grid, row_index, first_zero)
            marking_grid[row_index][first_zero] = "*"
        end
    end

    return mark(grid, marking_grid)
end


def mark grid, marking_grid, marked_rows = Array.new, marked_cols = Array.new
    marking_grid.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
        selected_assignment = row.index("*")
        if selected_assignment.nil? then
            marked_rows.push(row_index)
        end
    end

    marked_rows.each do |index|
        grid[index].each_with_index do |cost, col_index|
            if cost == 0 then
                marked_cols.push(col_index) 
            end
        end
    end
    marked_cols = marked_cols.uniq

    marked_cols.each do |col_index|
        marking_grid.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
            if row[col_index] == "*" then
                marked_rows.push(row_index) 
            end
        end
    end

    return [marked_rows, marked_cols]
end


def cross_out(marking_grid, row, col)
    if col != nil then
        marking_grid.each_index do |i|
            marking_grid[i][col] = "X"  
        end
    end
    if row != nil then
        marking_grid[row].map! {|i| "X"} 
    end
end

grid = [
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1],
]

p draw_lines(grid)
```